# sudo apt-get install apache2 does not fetch apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, apt

Trying out `sudo apt-get install apache2`, this is what I get:

```
root@x27:/home/test# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package apache2
```

Appreciate help for using apt-get for apache.

Comment: Is this on ubuntu or debian?

Comment: ubuntu..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `apt-get update` first.

Comment: done... that got apache running,
now apt-get install mysql does not seem to be found

is it mysql or another term?

Comment: try `apt-cache search mysql`

Comment: It's `mysql-server` or `mysql-client` depending on what you want. Next time try using `apt-cache search $SEARCH_TERM`, `aptitude search $SEARCH_TERM` or http://packages.ubuntu.com/ yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A good tip for finding packages:

`apt-cache search KEYWORD | grep KEYWORD`

e.g. `apt-cache search mysql | grep mysql`

`apt-cache search` will rattle off a lot of noise sometimes, which is why I use the grep pipe.

Comment: Don't forget `apt-cache policy PACKAGENAME` to show which one will be installed (version and source)